# Having trouble editing colors on a certain page on my wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to edit the colors of my user profile page on my site www.wastelandgamers.com/user-profile I would like for the fields tat are blue to be white instead and the text in those fields to be black instead of white.

I am able to change them when I use the developer tools through Google Chrome and get the desired look, however, I am not able to find the HTML doc that I need to change in order to get the look I want. I have searched through nearly all of the relevant site files using file manager through cPanel with no luck.

Here are a screen captures of before and after the color change using developer tools.

**Before code change:**

[image]

**After code change:**

[image]

**Code I need to change** (.entry-content towards bottom)

```html
.tml-profile {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.tml-profile .tml-form-table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tml-profile .tml-form-table th,
.tml-profile .tml-form-table td {
 display: block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: auto;
}

.tml-profile .screen-reader-text,
.tml-profile .screen-reader-text span {
 height: 1px;
 left: -1000em;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 width: 1px;
}

.tml-profile .wp-pwd {
 text-align: right;
}

.tml-profile .wp-pwd .dashicons {
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 1;
 height: 1em;
 width: 1em;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.tml-profile #pass-strength-result {
 margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.hidden,
.no-js .hide-if-no-js,
.js .hide-if-js {
 display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .tml-profile .tml-submit-wrap input {
  width: auto;
 }
}

.entry-content tr th, .entry-content thead th {
    color: #cbcbcb;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I am using the Parabola theme for my site and Theme my login for the profile page.

If anyone knows why I'm unable to find the file I need to edit or of another way to make the change I would really appreciate the help! If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: edit your question and input the code there, images are nice but code is needed. I'm not going to squint and try to copy the code to view it

Comment: The issue is that I can't find the file that I need to edit, so I'm not even sure where the code is. The best I can do is copy it from the developer tools. I'll do that and add it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of WordPress themes, but some of them do allow for custom CSS. Google found me this:

> we have created a special input field right in theme’s settings page.
>   You’ll find it by going to Appearance > Theme Settings, then expanding
>   the Miscellaneous Section by clicking on it. The Custom CSS field is a
>   bit further down.

You should see this: https://www.cryoutcreations.eu/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/themesettings-customcssjs.png

In this area (indicated by the blue box), you will want to PRECISELY recreate the code you have circled above (https://i.stack.imgur.com/00cxb.png) EXCEPT for changing the #colour to your desired colour.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I had been trying to find the file and edit it manually when the solution was much simpler, of course. Also, just because I'm curious, do you prefer another CMS or you're fine with WordPress but just don't like themes?

Comment: I see that you added some code above. For safety, you probably shouldn't touch it. Just add the code to their "custom code" area, as I suggest here.

Comment: Aha! We're stuck in a time warp. To answer your question, I think most CMS are overweight for the task they are needed for. I code raw PHP; but I've run into WordPress enough to know my way around. Cheers. That's for the approved answer and all the best.